# Attachment's name charset/encoding in IBM Notes Document

Tags: java, web-services, encoding, lotus-notes, mime

I have a web-service provider(Java), which imports a `.doc` file  to the  `NotesDocument`. The problem occurs with  files with Russian characters in their names - they aren't correctly transferred.
For example, if the `filename` will be equal to `Безымянный.doc`, it will be transferred as `Áåçûìÿííûé.doc`.

```
File directory = new File("C:\\Attachments 1C");
String filename = "Безымянный.doc"
String path = directory + "\\" + filename;
Stream outStream = sess.createStream();
sess.setConvertMIME(true);
MIMEEntity body = newDoc.createMIMEEntity("rtBody");

Stream inStream = sess.createStream();
if (inStream.open(path, "binary")) {
    if (inStream.getBytes() > 0) {
        do {
            byte[] buffer = inStream.read(32767);
            outStream.write(buffer);
        } while (!inStream.isEOS());
        inStream.close();

        MIMEEntity child = body.createChildEntity();

        String fileSuffix = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".")+1);

        child.setContentFromBytes(outStream, fileSuffix, MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);

        MIMEHeader header = child.createHeader("Content-Disposition");
        header.setHeaderVal("attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
        header = child.createHeader("Content-ID");
        header.setHeaderVal(path);
        outStream.truncate();
    }else 
        return "empty file";
}else 
    return "couldn't open the file";
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The standards for this are not quite final and the behavior will depend on what browser is being used. See the question and answers to [this previous question on StackOverflow](http://http:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http) for a detailed explanation and for information about what works with various browsers.

Comment: I don't work with browsers in this case. The file attaches to the  NotesDocument in the IBM Notes environment.

Comment: I tried this: String dispositionFileName = URLEncoder.encode(filename, "UTF-8") - doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by encoding the filename using MimeUtility(others don't work):

```
String filenameEndoded = MimeUtility.encodeText(filename,"Cp1251","B");
```